# comparar dos listas y obtener elemento según condición c#

Tags: c#, lista, objeto, comparaciones

Tengo dos listas de tipo 
Mi lista `List<MiObj> SoftwareEquipo = new List<MiObj>();`  que por medio de un foreach se le asigno el software con el que cuenta un equipo

ejemplo

```
id - nombre -      tipo -     EsUnico 

1    office 2013   ofimatica   true
3    solidworks    diseño      true
4    notepat       editor      false
```

y una segunda lista  `List<MiObj> SoftwareDisponible = new List<MiObj>();`

```
id - nombre -     tipo -     EsUnico 

2    office 365   ofimatica  true
5    VsCode       editor     false
```

como puedo hacer para que una tercer lista `List<MiObj> ListaFinal= new List<MiObj>();`
sea llenada con los datos de mi segunda lista SoftwareDisponible, con la condicion de que si el atributo tipo es igual a alguno de los atributos tipo de SoftwareEquipo y ademas el atributo EsUnico es true lo excluya en este caso el resltado esperado seria que mi tercer lista sea asi

```
id - nombre -     tipo -     EsUnico 
5    VsCode       editor     false
```

eh intentado con foreach pero no consigo obtener el resultado

si mi pregunta inflingue alguna regla pido me disculpen y me lo comenten para editarla gracias

Comment: nos mostras como lo intentaste? es justamente, un foreach dentro de otro, o linq, probablemente con join...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has intentado utilizar LinQ para este tipo de escenarios? suele ser útil para entenderlos por que puedes "jugar con las condiciones" te muestro como podria ser

```
foreach (var item in SoftwareDisponible.Where(x => SoftwareEquipo.Where(y => y.tipo == x.tipo && y.EsUnico != true).Select(y => y.tipo).Contains(x.tipo)  ))
                ListaFinal.Add(item);
```

Con datos parecidos a tu codigo:

```
List<MiObj> SoftwareEquipo = new List<MiObj>() {
    { new MiObj(){ id = 1 , nombre ="office 2013", tipo="ofimatica", EsUnico=true} },
    { new MiObj(){ id = 3 , nombre ="solidworks", tipo="diseño", EsUnico=true} },
    { new MiObj(){ id = 4 , nombre ="notepat", tipo="editor", EsUnico=false} },
};
List<MiObj> SoftwareDisponible = new List<MiObj>() {
    { new MiObj(){ id = 1 , nombre ="office 365", tipo="ofimatica", EsUnico=true} },
    { new MiObj(){ id = 3 , nombre ="VsCode", tipo="editor", EsUnico=false} },
};
List<MiObj> ListaFinal = new List<MiObj>();


foreach (var item in SoftwareDisponible.Where(x => SoftwareEquipo.Where(y => y.tipo == x.tipo && y.EsUnico != true).Select(y => y.tipo).Contains(x.tipo)  ))
    ListaFinal.Add(item);
```

Comment: Hola @stial tu respuesta me sirvió solo ay un detalle, me trae los datos que quiero excluir, en este caso el dato que me trae es `id = 1 , nombre ="office 365", tipo="ofimatica", EsUnico=true` y el dato que  realmente esperaba es `id = 3 , nombre ="VsCode", tipo="editor", EsUnico=false` ya intente invirtiendo la condicion y no funciona asi que usare el dato que me trae y tratare de excluiréle

Comment: lo acomode añadiendo la siguiente linea   `SoftwareDisponible = SoftwareDisponible .Except(ListaFinal).ToList();`

Comment: Esta curioso porque cuando lo calo si me trae el id 3 VsCode , al menos con las listas que le muestro. Pero igual como dice, al menos le sirve para hacer el Except(), muy bien.

Comment: Si la verdad funciono muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar investigar acerca de linq y lograr algo parecido a:

```
var newList = from sd in SoftwareDisponible 
                       join se in SoftwareEquipo on sd.tipo equals se.tipo
                       where sd.EsUnico == true
                       select sd;
```

El resumen de la consulta seria: Traer el listado de "SoftwareDisponible" haciendo donde el tipo corresponda con alguno de la lista SoftwareEquipo  y el campo "EsUnico" sea igual a true